# Расположение блоков css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

Здравствуйте подскажите как сделать такую верстку элементов на flexbox
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, почему именно на flexbox? Во-вторых, какую конкретно задачу решаете?

Comment: Задача связанна с адаптивом, первая картинка - горизонтальная адаптация, нижняя, вертикальная отображает на 2 элемента больше.

Comment: Адаптив не умеет превращать 6 элементов в 8. Ставь @media и стилизуй как хочешь.